# Move Queues between variables without copying elements

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference

I have several queues in an application, and I want to change where they are 'pointing' to, changing ones for the others.

For example, if I have:

```
queue<int> q1 = queue<int>();
queue<int> q2 = queue<int>();
queue<int> q3 = queue<int>();
```

There are several elements inside each of the queue, and I want to update q1, making it point to q2, and q2, making it point to q3, instead of copying the elements. Can I do something like:

```
q1 = &q2;
q2 = &q3;
q3 = queue<int>();
```

If so, how should I write that? Or do I have to transform those queues into pointers to queues, to be able to change where they are pointing to?

I would rather avoid pointers so I do not have to manage the memory explicitly.

Comment: `std::swap(q1, q2); std::swap(q2, q3); q3 = queue<int>();`

Comment: you are not using pointer. check pointer and reference usage in c++. it is one of basic concept in c++

Comment: @user657267: or `q1 = std::move(q2); q2 = std::move(q3); q3 = queue<int>();`

Comment: Try : queue<int> q1**;
queue<int> q2*;
queue<int> q3 = queue<int>();

q1 = &&q2;
q2 = &q3;
q3 = queue<int>();

Comment: @Adem I know I am not using pointers, but the same way I can send a queue as a reference, it might be possible to change where the queue referenced to, without relying on pointers directly.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, I lack some c++ knowledge on things like swap, move and such...just know the C way...

Comment: @BlunT , you can use a queue's reference. but you can not assign it to a non pointer variable, or you can not change a non pointer's reference address as I know. in your code, define a pointer like queue<int>* q4. and then you can assing q4 = &q1

Comment: @BlunT reference and pointers are same, just notation difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of copy, you may move elements (since C++11):

```
q1 = std::move(q2);
q2 = std::move(q3);
q3 = queue<int>();
```

so  `q1` holds previous resources from `q2`, `q2` holds previous resources from `q3` and `q3` is empty.