# How to efficiently transfer the contents of an std::queue to another in C++98?

Tags: c++, queue, c++98

In C++11 or higher, one can efficiently transfer all the contents of one `std:queue` instance to another `std::queue` instance through [std::move()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29510726/5762785). The system I am working with, however, is only C++98. How can I do the same operation (efficiently) in C++98?

Comment: `std::swap` perhaps.

Comment: hi @S.M., std::queue::swap I think is C++11? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/swap

Comment: hi @S.M., will using C++98's std::swap() be as time-efficient as C++11's std::move() or std::queue::swap()?

Comment: Not sure if it's available for std::queue in C++98, I assume, it's available, since it is available for std::deque, and std::queue is an adapter to std::deque.  Yes, it's fast like moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++98 you'd need to reach into the the protected `c` member, and swap *those* containers. Swapping is meant to be fast and exception safe (and indeed *is* for standard containers), and is the idiom one would use prior to the addition of `std::move`.

You can do that with derivation, and pointers to members.

```
template<typename E, class C>
void swapQueues(std::queue<E, C>& lhs, std::queue<E, C>& rhs) {
    struct peek : std::queue<E, C> {
        using std::queue<E, C>::c; // Grant access
    };
    C std::queue<E, C>::* ptr = &peek::c;
    (lhs.*ptr).swap(rhs.*ptr);
}
```

We derive `peek`  from the queue type so as to obtain a class type that can access the `c` member. We then immediately expose that member in `peek`.

Following that, we fetch a pointer to the member through the public `peek::c`. Pointer-to-member conversion is implicit here, allowing us to initialize a pointer-to-member of `std::queue`.

And finally, it's a simple matter of applying the pointer-to-member to get a reference to each queue's underlying container, and swapping them.

[Here it is live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NQunzza8MOl6o9KD)